# What is the recommended way to find the (position/velocity) indices of a free body in the `MultibodyPlant` state vector?

Tags: drake

There are a number of use cases where we want to introspect the state vector coming out of the `MultibodyPlant` `get_state_output_port`.  As a simple example, imagine I am logging the state output port and just want to label my axes (or know which axes to plot).

What is the recommended API for this?
For joints, I know that we can iterate through joints (e.g. via `get_joints()`) and then ask each joint for it’s position/velocities indices.  Do we have something similar for free bodies?

I know we can get the actual positions/velocities of a free body in a number of ways, given a context, but didn’t actually see the way to get the indices?

It’s tempting to say “just log with `get_state_output_port(model_instance)`”, but this particular  `MultibodyPlant` is buried inside a `Diagram` (like `MultibodyPlant`).

Answer (score 4):

If you don't mind iterating through all of the bodies (similarly to the joint cast mentioned above), you should be able to call `is_floating()` on each body, then if that returns true, check `floating_positions_start()` and `floating_velocities_start()` for the indices in the state vector.  There isn't a way to get the number of positions/velocities, but it looks like `has_quaternion_dofs()` is [being used as a proxy](https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/blob/4087631ea6db0251ff0e2f8911caadff0000a04f/multibody/inverse_kinematics/global_inverse_kinematics.cc#L225) for that functionality.

note: I didn't actually code up a test to make sure that this idea works.

Comment: Thank you @sammy-tri. The reason there's no methods for getting the number of positions/velocities is because the number of velocities is always 3 while the number of positions is 3 or 4. As you mentioned, you can use `has_quaternion_dofs()` as a proxy for "4".

Comment: FWIW -- The API might soon allow better introspection.  There is a discussion on the issue at https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/issues/10736